# Testing font files with freetype

Tags: c++, fonts, sfml, freetype, fontforge

I have a bitmap .FON font I made with softy (a font editor), it seems to open fine with fontforge, I generated bdf, otf, fnt and otb files with it. The font looks a lot like profont, except it's proportional (not monospace). The glyph height is thus quite small (less than 15 pixels), so I don't know if ttf might work well...

SFML can't display any one of them, any advice ?

Code:

```
sf::Font font;
font.loadFromFile("filename");
text.setFont(font);
```

I checked, the font is opened. I know nothing about fonts with fontforge and freetype, and what format is better or might have more odds to work.

Comment: Why are you not checking the return value from loadFromFile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not possible. SFML actually requires font to have an unicode charset, which no bitmap font format supports.